# PurgeCSS: how to match css with backslash

Tags: javascript, css-purge

I am using csspurge using the config file. I have css written as
`lg\:right-40` and in js it is referred as `lg:right-40`.
in js backslash is escaped hence purgecss is not able identify all the that contain `\`

**cssfile**

```
.lg\:right-40 {
    right: 10rem;
}
.lg\:right-44 {
    right: 11rem;
}
.lg\:right-48 {
    right: 12rem;
}
.lg\:right-52 {
    right: 13rem;
}
.lg\:right-56 {
    right: 14rem;
}
```

***purgecss.config.js***

```
   const TailwindExtractor = (content) => {
  // Treat every word in the bundle as a CSS selector
  return content.match(/[\w-/\\:]+(?<!:)/g) || []
}
    new PurgeCSS().purge({
      content: ['./src/**/*.jsx', './src/**/*.js'],
      css: ['./src/login/tailwind_backup.css'],
      safelist:{
        greedy:[/\\/]
      },
      extractors: [{
        extractor: TailwindExtractor,
        extensions: ['js', 'jsx'],
      }],
      output: './src/login/tailwind.css'
    })
```

I want to match css classes with `\` with js classes without `\`

Comment: The problem is moot as slash characters are invalid for use in CSS class names. You should remove them.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan  .\32xl\:inset-1\/2 classes like these need backslash

Comment: They won't if you remove the invalid characters. Valid CSS class names can only contain a-z, - and _

Comment: these are from tailwind which is already used. can't remove them now

Comment: Tailwind is broken. *[In CSS](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#characters), identifiers (including element names, classes, and IDs in selectors) can contain only the characters [a-zA-Z0-9] and ISO 10646 characters U+00A0 and higher, plus the hyphen (-) and the underscore (_).* The colon is U+003A, which is below U+00A0.